# QTime to String with AM/PM and installed translator

Tags: qt, localization, internationalization, qdatetime, qtime

This little application make some problems:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator();
  QString langCode = "en_GB";
  translator->load(QString("Core_%1.qm").arg(langCode));
  QCoreApplication::installTranslator(translator);

  auto now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
  qDebug() << now.toString(tr("Timeformat"));

  return 0
}
```

For every language I create a separate **Core.qm** containing a translation for Timeformat. This is for "en_GB"

```
<message>
  <source>Timeformat</source>
  <translation>hh:mm ap</translation>
  <comment/>
</message>
```

And this is for "de_DE"

```
<message>
  <source>Timeformat</source>
  <translation>hh.mm</translation>
  <comment/>
</message>
```

The system language setting can be different then the loaded language file. If Software is running on a English laptop at 13:57 with loaded **Core_de_DE.qm** it displays *13.57*. ANd with loaded  **Core_en_GB.qm** it show **01:57 pm**.

But when the Software running on a french laptop with loaded **Core_en_GB.qm** (because my Software has no french translation). The Software show **01:57** (the **pm** is missing). Why?

Answer (score 0):

I've soled this by using the UK Local for every **toString** call instead of the system one:

```
//instead of
qDebug() << now.toString(tr("Timeformat"));
// I use now
qDebug() << QLocale("en_GB").toString(now, tr("Timeformat"));
```